# NestJS validation

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs

here is my detail code
create-task.dto.ts

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';
export class CreateTaskDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  title: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  description: string;
}
```

tasks.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Task, TaskStatus } from './task.model';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { CreateTaskDto } from './dto/create-task.dto';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  private tasks: Task[] = [];

  createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Task {
    const { title, description } = createTaskDto;
    const task: Task = {
      id: uuid(),
      title,
      description,
      status: TaskStatus.OPEN,
    };
    this.tasks.push(task);
    return task;
  }

  createTasks(createTasksDto: CreateTaskDto[]): Task[] {
    const tasks: Task[] = createTasksDto.map((task) => this.createTask(task));
    return tasks;
  }
}
```

tasks.controller.ts

```
import {
  Body,
  Post,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';
import { Task } from './task.model';
import { CreateTaskDto } from './dto/create-task.dto';

@Controller('tasks')
export class TasksController {
  constructor(private tasksService: TasksService) {}

  @Post()
  createTask(@Body() createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Task {
    return this.tasksService.createTask(createTaskDto);
  }

  @Post('/create-tasks')
  createTasks(@Body() createTasksDto: CreateTaskDto[]): Task[] {
    return this.tasksService.createTasks(createTasksDto);
  }
```

task.module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TasksController } from './tasks.controller';
import { TasksService } from './tasks.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [TasksController],
  providers: [TasksService],
})
export class TasksModule {}
```

When i test create 1 task it run correctly. However, when I want to apply the validation for creating many tasks, it didn't work. The response still run correctly without any error. Can anyone help me this

Comment: "However, when I want to apply the validation for creating many tasks, it didn't work."

Please elaborate on this. What is expected behavior, and what is the outcome you're currently getting?

Comment: @Krissh well i create a single task without fully information like the title or the description(one of these props or both are empty), it will cause an error (which i expected). However it not actually work when i create a list of tasks, one of the tasks isn't provided fully title or the description(one of these props or both are empty) it still run ok without any error. i want the app return the error in this situation. thanks for your help